# Input "datetime-local" allow only certain hours and dates

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, date, input

so I want to have an input which someone can select a date for example 4/6/2021 and then a period of time:

```
1-3 pm
3-5 pm
5-7 pm
7-10 pm
```

One of the above only

I would like to use `<input type="datetime-local"/>`, to achieve that but if there is any better way please let me know

Edit: I am using Nextjs - React

Comment: You could use a library like react-datepicker, it will make your life way easier than manipulating the default input tag

Comment: https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-exclude-times

Comment: If the time periods are fixed, then just use a select element with appropriate options.